# How to create tf.data.Dataset from the list of paths to images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to create td.data.Dataset instance and I know paths of images of input and output (it's an image-to-image neural net). I know that I can create tf.data.Dataset using `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()` but this is not my case because I need to use specifically the train-val-test split that is specified in one text file, and also moving the images to the specific folders are tedious and seems an inefficient way to do the task.

Comment: What have you worked out thus far? Lookup `ImageDataGenerator`.

Comment: @lukasz-tracewski now I use `class DataGen(tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence)`

Comment: I have no idea what this class is. Check the `ImageDataGenerator` and see if you can get it to work. If you encounter a problem you can't solve, provide the code and detailed description.

Comment: Can you give an example of this text file?

Comment: folder0/img0_input.png folder2/img0_output.png \n folder0/img1_input.png folder2/img1_output.png

Comment: For image data generator, you will have to create the folders again.